# Netcat connection closes after connecting through python

Tags: linux, macos, networking, python, netcat

So I have installed Netcat on my raspberry pi and my mac and I can get them to connect really easily. Problem is that if I want a python script on my mac to establish the connection when the raspberry pi is already listening for a connection. It will connect, but then it will close the connection imediatly. I use this code.

`Import os
os.popen("nc -v [MY IP] [Port]")`

The reason I want to do this is so I can send commands via python over Netcat E.g.

```
os.popen("Hello other computer")
```

How can I fix this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably that `nc` is a two-way connection, but `popen()` only
uses one way. When the remote server tries to read from the connection, nc will read from its stdin, which you are not setting, so it probably gets eof and so the connection closes.

Instead of `popen()` use the bidirectional `subprocess.Popen()`.

```
import subprocess
cmd = "nc -v [MY IP] [Port]"
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

You can then do `msg = p.stdout.readline()` or `p.stdin.write("reply\n")`,
or `p.communicate(...)` as described in the [online docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) or by `pydoc subprocess.Popen`.

---

Alternatively, and more simply, you can replace `nc` and use sockets natively in python. It's not particularly difficult. For example, as a client:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((MY_IP, PORT))
s.send('Hello, world')
print s.recv(1024) # read reply
s.close()
```

Comment: Thankyou. I think i still may use the subprocess over the the native python sockets because at the other end is a raspberry pi using servoblaster. So with the subprocess I dont need to use python at the pi side. Also with nc it really simple to write to the servoblaster device file using '> /dev/servoblaster' but with the sockets I would have to open the device file  then write to it and then flush it or close it or something.